# getting <td> id with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I am new to javascript and I jquery and I am trying to take the id of  element and the value of the element.

So this is the first ajax request:

```
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Home/AddText",
    data: JSON.stringify({ text: newText }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (result) {
        idRow = result.id;
        $("#myTable").append("<tr id = row" + idRow + "><td id = text>" +
            result.text + "</td><td>" +

            "<input type=checkbox id=checkbox onclick=CrossOut(" + idRow + ")>" + " " +

            "<a class=btnEdit onclick=Edit(" + idRow + ")>Edit</a>" +  " " +

                //show this buttons only if the edit button is clicked
                "<a class=btnSave onclick=Save(" + idRow + ")>Save</a>" + " " +

                "<a class=btnCancel onclick=Cancel(" + idRow + ")>Cancel</a>" + " " +

            "<a class=btnDelete onclick=Delete(" + idRow + ")>Delete</a>"

            + "</td> </tr>");

        idRow++;

        $(document).find('#text').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
        $(document).find('.btnSave').hide();
        $(document).find('.btnCancel').hide();
    }
})
```

And this is the function:

```
function Save(idRow) {

var newText = $("#text").val();
console.log(newText);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Home/Update",
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: idRow, text: newText }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (result) {
        $("#text").add(newText);

        $(document).find('.btnSave').hide();
        $(document).find('.btnCancel').hide();
        $(document).find('.btnEdit').show();
    }
})
```

}

So when I log the newText variable it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Why not using quotes in <td id = text>?

Comment: Because I have this function before                 
    var tbl_row = $(document).find('#row' + idRow);

    tbl_row.find('#text').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    tbl_row.find('.btnSave').show();
    tbl_row.find('.btnCancel').show();
    tbl_row.find('.btnEdit').hide();
}                     And it work without quotes

Comment: Ids must be unique in the doc. You have many inputs with id = text.

Comment: Why don't you use a JSX template or something along those lines, so you can append the template to your table with a replace {{ }} on items that will be populated?  Also, your doing a document level find for hiding and showing, you might want to adjust that.  Where you grab the specific element.

Comment: Thank you guys, I changed the id to be text1 and it worked. :D

Comment: Nadia if that helped you should mark the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with `td` you need to use `.text()`

```
var newText = $("#text").text();
```

Also note that you might have more than one unique `id` if you keep adding rows and the `$(#text)` would only get you the first one.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep this in might.